# Search Through Array, Return Results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I'm trying to incorporate a search function that returns the arrays that matches the title. Right now, it returns only an exact match. I want something similar to [this filter table function](http://this%20filter%20table%20function) where whenever I type in a letter, the results narrow down. Here is what I'm working with and what my data looks like.

```
let movies = [
{title: "Pacific Rim", year: "2018"}, 
{title: "Batman", year:"1984"},
{title: "Super Troopers 2", year: "2018"}
]

let filteredMovies = movies.filter(movie => {
        if (this.state.query.length === 0) {
          return movie;
        } else {
          return movie.title === this.state.query;
        }
      });
```

Should I be using `.filter`? Maybe some sort of regexp?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you even read the documentation on [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to find all titles that have the string:

```js
const movies = [{"title":"Pacific Rim","year":"2018"},{"title":"Batman","year":"1984"},{"title":"Super Troopers 2","year":"2018"}];

const query = 'roop';

// if query length is 0 use a copy of movies, else get the filtered result
const filteredMovies = query.length ? movies.filter(movie => {
  return movie.title.includes(query);
}) : [...movies];

console.log(filteredMovies);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test ignoring case then you can use a regex

`(new RegExp(this.state.query,"i")).test(movie.title)`